# What is an efficient way to exclude all results from a sql query?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, optimization

Surprised I haven't seen this before, but googling doesn't yield much insight.

I'm working with a framework that is going to generate a SQL query, like it or not.  I have the ability to add filtering on the query, and a case has arisen where I wish to exclude all possible results.

My initial thought is to add `WHERE 1 = 0` to the WHERE clause of the query.

Is there a more optimized or efficient way to do this?

Since this answer could vary between platforms, this will be run on SQL Server 2008

Comment: I'm sure that the optimizer knows that 1 is not 0, so this seems to be an efficient way.

Comment: Yeah that was my guess too, but I figured better to find out than just go with my own assumption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are correct, this is the best and most frequently used way to exclude all results from a query:

```
WHERE 1=0
```

Comment: it is better to provide a link to an official document that states this.

Comment: If someone provides a better answer I will update the selected answer.

Answer (score 1):

`WHERE 1 = 0` is the most common method.  Creating temp table structures with `SELECT ... INTO #temp WHERE 1 = 0` is pretty common.

Be advised that this condition can cause the query engine to short circuit the query planning, so be careful if you use it for query analysis.

Comment: Meaning that the analysis could produce unexpected results?  Sounds like in terms of production its an acceptable solution.

Comment: @JustinStandard Meaning, say, a query execution plan wouldn't be applicable.  If you're debugging a query plan, it's no good.  You didn't specify a context for the question.